# Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/bootstrap.min.js”

Tags: django, ajax

I'm getting the error "Loading failed for the  with source “http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/bootstrap.min.js”." and my ajax is also not working. I want to delete a django form without refreshing my page

```
def client_delete(request, pk):
    data = {'success': False}
    client = Client.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        try:
            client.delete()
            if client:
                data['success']=True
            else:
                data['success'] = False
                data['error'] = "unsuccessful!"
        except Client.DoesNotExist:
            return redirect('/NewApp/clientlist')
return JsonResponse(json.dumps(data))
```

In my client_list.py file,

```
{% block javascript %}
<script src="{% static '/js/app.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static '/js/jquery-3.2.1.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static '/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4           /jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.marquee@1.5.0  /jquery.marquee.min.js"></script>
{% endblock %}

<script>
document.getElementById("print").addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("deleted")
    alert('ok');
    var id = $(this).attr('name');
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: 'NewApp/clientdelete' + id,
        data:{
            csrfmiddlewaretoken:   $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
        },
       success: function(data){
          if(data.success == true){
         alert("success");
       }
       }
   });
  return(false);
});
```

Comment: Well do you have that script in your static folder? And why don't you use a CDN version like you do for jQuery? (And why are you loading three different versions of jQuery?)

Comment: yes, the script file is in static/js directory and as per your say, I have added cdn links of both jquery amd bootstrap. But now it's telling me "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://html.codedthemes.com/flash-able/bootstrap/assets/fonts/fontawesome/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)." I have installed and configured "django-CORS-headers." but still I'm getting the same error. Also my Ajax is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Try the path in the template without the leading "/" infront of js. It should look like {% static 'js/app.js' %} and make sure to use {% load static %} or {% load staticfiles %} based on your template.